# Why partial fraction decomposition requires a proper fraction on input?

Tags: partial-fractions

Is this only a desirable condition to make the job easier or a strict constraint of the method itself?

("Proper fraction" = a fraction where numerator is smaller then denominator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find constants $A$ and $B$ here:
$$
\frac{x^{10}}{x(1-x)} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{1-x}
$$
If you cannot do it, you have your reason...

(I assume "poper fraction" means; degree of numerator is less than degree of denominator.)

**added**
All the terms for a partial fraction decomposition go to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.  So if you add them all together, still you have something at goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.  The only rational functions with that property are the "proper" rational functions.

Comment: I see that in this example trying to find constant values for _A_ and _B_ leads to a nonvalid solution, but **why** does it happen so?